# Google Map not loading now that site is in HTTPS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I recently secured my site but now the map will not load. When I opened the console I see "***Mixed Content: The page at (website) was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDiLzNYHxkTptta2UKrWAPyc8vsOkbluEc&sensor=false&libraries=places'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.***" - I

Anyone have any insight?

The site is gearbottle.com/find

Comment: Change http to https.

Answer (score 2):

Scripts, stylesheets and some other "active" resources must be served securely on a secure (https://) domain. In your case, changing the protocol from "http" to "https" for the Google Maps API (at line 110) will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The Google Maps JavaScript API, Google Static Maps API, and Google Maps APIs web services can be accessed over secure (HTTPS) connections by developers using either the free version of these APIs or Google Maps APIs Premium Plan. Please see the documentation for the API concerned for information on how to access the API over SSL.
>
> Note that the Google Static Maps API does not support custom icon URLs that use HTTPS; the default icon will be displayed.

[Google Maps APIs Premium Plan](http://www.google.com/enterprise/maps/)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line on Googlemaps.php on line 44 to TRUE

```
var $https                      = TRUE;
```